# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, apk

**build.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.classic"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
}
```

While `Generating APK` getting :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>       File1: /home/sun/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/11393498b38e9695d0850cac26fde5613ae268b9/httpcore-4.3.jar
>       File2: /home/sun/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3/5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7/httpmime-4.3.jar

**Updated # 2**

I have copied `jars` into `libs` folder and getting

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
>       File1: /home/sun/AndroidStudioProjects/Classic/app/libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar
>       File2: /home/sun/AndroidStudioProjects/Classic/app/libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar
>       File3: /home/sun/AndroidStudioProjects/Classic/app/libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar

here is updated `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.classic"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile files('libs/pgsdk.jar')
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
}
```

Comment: Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your app `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @PratikButani tried still getting same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding that files in the packaging:

```
android {
    packagingOptions { 
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        (...)
    }
}
```